What permissions to use when logging into Instagram via the Facebook login
What permissions to use when logging into Instagram via the Facebook login as when I use scope=instagram_basic,pages_show_list is says these are invalid.
I am trying to update the app code to connect with Instagram accounts. The examples I am following still use instagram_basic and pages_show_list for logging into a business or creator account using Instagram API with Facebook login. However when executed, the message returned is "Invalid Scopes: instagram_basic, pages_show_list" and I am not finding what permissions to use in their place. What would be the correct permissions for accessing user account images?
